# How to raise KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.swipeLeft() method in the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to raise the KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.swipeLeft() method when I am running my Input Method in the emulator. Is there any way? Or I have to run it in a real device? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't raise this event via the emulator. You hae to deploy it on a real device.